# Emit format in C# UWP

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, uwp, socket.io

So I created a nodejs server like this :

```
var io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);

// Handle chat event
socket.on('chat', function(data){
    console.log(data);
    io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
});
```

with nice UI and work out perfectly with this JavaScript function:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
socket.emit('chat', {
  message: message.value,
  handle: handle.value
 });
 });
```

and got the result like this

```
made socket connection eo96mhJ1_RwG9WYMAAAR
{ message: 'Hello', handle: 'From the Browser' }
```

Now I want my UWP application connect to server and emit the message just like the front-end on the server 
I use "SocketIOClientDotNet" nuget

here is the code:

```
var socket = IO.Socket("ws://localhost:8888");
socket.Connect();
ReceivedText.Text = "Connect Completed";
socket.Emit("chat", "This is a message from UWP...");
```

and the console reply:

```
made socket connection 8rRfm0gOmJeg9orIAAAe
This is a message from UWP...
```

the problem here is: I want the emit message have the same exact same format as the front-end so It could display like this :

```
{ message: 'Hello', handle: 'From UWP' }
```

which is params object[] in C# have work like the JavaScript frontend in the socket.Emit but I don't know it's syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is JSON based, so you can use Json.NET for this.

First install [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) from NuGet:

```
> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 12.0.1
```

Create a class:

```
public class SocketMessage
{
   public string Message {get;set;}
   public string Handle {get;set;}
}
```

And now use Json.NET to serialize instance of this object:

```
var message = new SocketMessage()
{
   Message = "Hello",
   Handle = "From UWP"
};
socket.Emit("chat", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));
```